# Ver los registros de una tabla usando express y mssql

Tags: sql-server, nodejs, express

Al seguir los ejemplos de la pagina oficial de mssql https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql
usando node y express estoy tratando de traer todos los registros de mi tabla usuarios que se encuentra en una base de datos sql server para mostrarlos en formato json en el navegador pero al correr node me marca el siguiente error:

```
TypeError: pool.query is not a function
```

conn.js

```
const sql = require('mssql')

const config =  {
    user: '***',
    password: '*****',
    server: '****', 
    database: '****',
}

async function pool() {
    const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);

    try {
        await pool.connect();
        console.log('Connected to database');
        return pool;
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log('Database connection failed!', err);
        return err;
    }
}

module.exports = pool;
```

usuarios.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const pool = require('../db/conn');


router.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    pool.query('SELECT*FROM Usuarios', (err, rows,fields)=>{
        if(!err){
            res.json(rows);
        } else{
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});

module.exports=router;
```

Comment: Hola nunca use la libreria pero creo que en el doc de npm te dice que `const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);` le faltaria  `const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config).connect();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenias razon @tzanuttini adjunto el codigo por si sirve de ayuda para alguna persona que quiera hacer uso de la libreria mssql para conectarse a una base de datos SQL SERVER en Node js con async/await y conexion pool

conn.js

```
const sql = require('mssql')
    //conexion a la base de datos
        const config = {
            "user": "*****", 
            "password": "*******",
            "server": "******", // 
            "database": "*****", // nombre de tu base de datos

          }

        const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
        const poolConnect = pool.connect();

        pool.on('error', err => {
            console.log("Sql database connection error " ,err);
        })

        async function messageHandler() {
            await poolConnect; 
            try {
                const request = pool.request(); 
                const result = request.query('select 1 as number')
                console.dir(result)
                return result;
            } catch (err) {
                console.error('SQL error', err);
            }
        }
         module.exports= pool;
```

user.js

```
  const express = require('express');
    const router = express.Router();
    const pool = require('../db/conn');

 //ruta  para ver los datos de mi tabla en formato json en el navegador   
    router.get('/',(req,res)=>{
        pool.query('SELECT*FROM "MiTabla"', (err, rows,fields)=>{
            if(!err){
                res.json(rows);
            } else{
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    });

    module.exports=router;
```

index,js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
//Settings
app.set('port',process.env.PORT || 3000);
//Middlewares
app.use(express.json());
//rutas 
app.use(require('./routes/user'));

//starting the server
app.listen(app.get('port'),()=>{
    console.log('server on port:', app.get('port'));
});
```